# determine quotient space of image of a matrix in kernel of another matrix to determine homology group

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, modules

I have $A = \mathbb{Z}^a$, $B = \mathbb{Z}^b$, and $C = \mathbb{Z}^c$, where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$

I also have a matrix of integers $L:A \to B$, and $L':B \to C$ and know (from the context which they arose) that $\mathrm{range}(L) \subseteq \mathrm{ker}(L')$.

How can I calculate the quotient group $\mathrm{ker}(L')/\mathrm{range}(L)$ computationally.

---

For example suppose I have $a = 1; b = 3; c=3$

$$
L =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
and

$$
L' =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1& 1& 0 \\
    -1& 0&1 \\
    0& -1& -1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

I can do row operations to find invertible $R$ so that

$$RL' =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1& 0& -1 \\
    0& 1& 1 \\
    0& 0& 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

And I know that the null space of $L'$ is generated by $(1, -1, 1)^T$, which equals the image of $L$, so the quotient space is trivial.

---

Edit: I'm trying to compute the homology group for explicitly provided boundary operators.

Comment: This guy seems to do it. https://jeremykun.com/2013/04/10/computing-homology/

Comment: That link seems to discuss the easier case of coefficients in a field. You can probably do something similar using the Hermite normal form instead of usual column reduction